# Why can't avoid config before compile Linux kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, compiling, configuration, make

I copied `myconfig` file, into /`tmp/build/.config`

And, `make O=/tmp/build/ vmlinux`.

And it keeps asking me to config again.

I tried to `make O=/tmp/build menuconfig`, and load the myconfig.

Still, before compiling proceeds, the `/tmp/build/.config` was altered.

I just want to compile the Linux kernel with the specific `.config` file.

Comment: Your `.config` is from an older kernel, and kernel want you to set the new config lines, which are missing from yours. Do `make menuconfig`

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy your existing kernel config file before compiling:

```
cp /boot/config-$(uname -r) .config
```